# linq join tables with select subquery?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, linq

SQL query like the following and I'm trying to make it LinQ,,but it is not working sql working but linq not working... where is my error?

```
select (select X from X where X.yid=Y.id and X.FormNo=4),* 
from Y 
where Y.servicetype=3
```

this sql query is working

```
public IEnumerable<NBelge> BelgeleriGetir2(int servicetype, int formno)
{
    var db = new SERVISBAKIMEntities();
    var result = (from g in db.Y
                  join d in db.X
                  on g.id equals d.yid into ps
                  from d in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  where g.servicetype == servicetype && d.FormNo == formno
                  select new {});
}
```

linq code like this but it is not working? where is true way?

Comment: So you show a sql query and a working linq query, but where is your non-working linq query?

Comment: first code block is working sql query and second code block is not working linq statement,thanks

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? Are you getting an error? What's the error? Are you getting unexpected results? What are the result you're getting and how do they differ from the results you're expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct, using the sub query, is this:

```
var result = (from y in db.Y
              where y.servicetype == 3
              select new { y, x = (from x in db.X 
                                   where x.yid == y.id && x.FormNo == 4 
                                   select x.x).FirstOrDefault() }
             ).ToList();
```

But I think the use of `join` is more readable. In sql it will look like this:

```
select X.x, Y.*
from Y
join X on Y.id == X.yid
where Y.servicetype == 3
and X.FormNo == 4
```

Using linq:

```
var result = (from y in db.Y
              where y.servicetype == 3
              join x in db.X on y.id equals x.yid
              where x.FormNo == 4
              select new { y, x }).ToList();
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `select x` in the sub query?

Comment: @NetMage - in his original sql he selects field x from table x: `select X from X` so I kept it that way for the first linq

Comment: Yes, but you have `select x.x` as the result, not `select x`

Comment: @NetMage - it's been a while since the question :) can you remind me what you mean?